# How to get sum and average of two columns using dplyr R

Tags: r

I have columns as follows

```
EndoID      NumBx     CStage
1            2          1
1            8          1
1            3          1
2            1          4
3            2          10
3            1          10
4            3          3
```

The Cstage is the same for each EndoId

I would like to get the sum of NumBx for each EndoId but I would also like to see the CStage in the results. SO far I can't get to see the C Stage

Here is my code

```
GroupedByEndo <- PragueSubset %>% group_by(EndoID) %>% summarise(Sum = sum(NumBx))
```

The output I woud like is:

```
EndoID         NumBx     CStage
    1            13         1
    2            1          4
    3            3          10
    4            3          3
```

but instead I get

```
 EndoID         NumBx     
        1            13         
        2            1          
        3            3         
        4            3
```

Comment: Yes. I want the average of cStage because then I know it will be the same for all the same EndoIds.

Comment: Marked down because why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the `mean` of SCstage, or the `first`

```
PragueSubset <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 
"EndoID      NumBx     CStage
1            2          1
1            8          1
1            3          1
2            1          4
3            2          10
3            1          10
4            3          3")

GroupedByEndo <- PragueSubset %>% 
                   group_by(EndoID) %>% 
                   summarise(Sum = sum(NumBx), CStage = first(CStage))
GroupedByEndo 
Source: local data frame [4 x 3]

  EndoID   Sum CStage
   (int) (int)  (int)
1      1    13      1
2      2     1      4
3      3     3     10
4      4     3      3
```

Comment: Aha. Didnt realise you could just comma add another one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit hacky solution,  but it does the job.

```
 df  %>% group_by(EndoID) %>%
         mutate(NumBoxS = sum(NumBx), Cstage2 = mean((CStage)))  %>%
         summarise_each(funs = "mean")  %>% select(-c(NumBx, Stage))

 Source: local data frame [4 x 3]

  EndoID NumBoxS Cstage2
   (int)   (dbl)   (dbl)
1      1      13       1
2      2       1       4
3      3       3      10
4      4       3       3
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get the result you're asking for with:

```
GroupedByEndoAndCstage <- PragueSubset %>% group_by(EndoID,Cstage) %>% summarise(Sum = sum(NumBx))
```